# Submitting user feedback data to Elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs, forms, feedback

I'm trying to use this [angular bootstrap feedback form](https://robertyoung.github.io/angular-bootstrap-feedback/) to collect user feedback data and index the information to Elasticsearch (to make it searchable).

So in my searchService for Elasticsearch, I simply did:

```
this.userSearchFeedback = function (userFeedbackForm) {
    esClient.index({
      index: 'searchfeedback-index1',
      type: 'general',
      opType: 'index',
      refresh: true,
      body: {
        fields: ['comments', 'email']
      }
    }).then(function(es_return) {
      console.log('success');
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  };
```

userFeedbackForm is the name of the form, which looks like this:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        We would love to hear your thoughts and suggestions on what we get right and wrong - it helps us improve our services to you. Your feedback is appreciated and helps us get better!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <pre>Model: {{comments | json}}</pre>
        <label for="description_field" class="control-label">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Please describe your issue or share your feedback!" name="comments" ng-model="comments" style="min-height: 165px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- /DESCRIPTION -->
      <!-- EMAIL -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <pre>Model: {{email | json}}</pre>
        <label for="email_field" class="control-label">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="email" />
      </div>
      <!-- /EMAIL -->
    </div>
```

I've added ng-models for both inputs and added those in my controller

```
//initialize feedback form
$scope.feedback = {
  comments: '',
  email: ''
};
```

The module already comes with a function that is called from ng-click on the form template...

```
function submitButtonPressed(form) {
console.log("Submit button pressed");
console.log(form);
console.log($scope.feedback.comments);//added
console.log($scope.feedback.email);//added
```

and that is where I'm stuck.

What else do I need to do with the function in order for it to call the userSearchFeedback() in my searchService so that the form data can be indexed to ES?

Comment: You haven't defined a specific problem or shown us all relevant code as per [mcve]. The form shown doesn't even have any form controls. Need a lot more detail here

Comment: @charlietfl your right - I've been in such a rush today, I threw this up. I'm looking at the code now and realizing all that is missing. Once I get his handled I'll post back so others can benefit(if they need it).

Comment: Well nobody can help if the specific problem is unknown and relevant code related to that problem is not provided

Comment: @charlietfl I've edited the question with some add'l info, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After just trial and error with the above posted. I decided to look to see if there was something else available. There [is and its amazingly simple](https://github.com/jacobscarter/angular-feedback) to implement. Just add the url to submit to and your done! Had it up and running in just a few minutes (once I realized I had to supply a url).

HTH anyone.